# Use of shift when parsing command-line parameters

Tags: batch-file

```
C:\Temp> type test.bat
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
if "%~1" == "-c" (shift & set str=%1)
echo str = %str%
echo arg = %1


C:\Temp>test -c foo
str = -c
arg = foo
```

I predicted that the above batch file would populate the variable 'str' with the text 'foo'.
But obviously I'm mistaken.
I'm trying to understand the results ... does shift delay its effects in some fashion?

Separating the 'shift' and the 'set' onto separate lines does not change the result:

```
C:\Temp> type test.bat
if "%~1" == "-c" (
  shift
  set str=%1
)
echo str = %str%
echo arg = %1

C:\Temp> test.bat -c foo
str = -c
arg = foo
```

Although the variant below does produce what I consider to be more predictable output:

```
C:\Temp> type test.bat
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
if "%~1" == "-c" shift
set str=%1
echo str = %str%

C:\Temp>test -c foo
str = foo
```

Why does shift appear to 'delay' its behavior?

BTW: I'm trying to implement named parameters, e.g. something like this:

```
REM Grab command-line parameters
:PARSE
if "%~1"=="" goto ENDPARSE
if "%~1"=="-c" set ipaddr=%1
if "%~1"=="-i" set iterations=%1
if "%~1"=="-s" set sleepTime=%1
if "%~1"=="-w" set window=%1
if "%~1"=="-l" set length=%1
if "%~1"=="-p" set port=%1
if "%~1"=="-d" set duration=%1
if "%~1"=="-b" set bandwidth=%1
if "%~1"=="-f" set output=%1
if "%~1"=="-d" set debug=%1
shift
goto PARSE
:ENDPARSE
```

Answer (score 1):

Ah - `delay` - that's the keyword. Search SO for `delayedexpansion`. I've never tried `!1` and I doubt it'd work...

Within a block statement `(a parenthesised series of statements)`, the **entire** block is parsed and **then** executed. Any `%var%` within the block will be replaced by that variable's value **at the time the block is parsed** - before the block is executed - the same thing applies to a `FOR ... DO (block)`.

Hence, `IF (something) else (somethingelse)` will be executed using the values of `%variables%` at the time the `IF` is encountered.

The same applies to parameters. `%1` is replaced by the value of `%1` at the time the `if` statement is **parsed** which is why you aren't seeing it change with `shift`.

Perhaps you could try (need I say this is but one line, you have many... somethimes that's necessary)

```
if "%~1"=="-d" set debug=%2
shift
shift
goto parse
```

which should deliver what you require. Note that `if /i ...` will make the `if` case-insensitive, if that's required.

Answer (score 1):

This should work: it assumes that there will always be a pair of items per switch

```
@echo off
REM Grab command-line parameters
:PARSE
if /i "%~1"=="-c" set "ipaddr=%~2"
if /i "%~1"=="-i" set "iterations=%~2"
if /i "%~1"=="-s" set "sleepTime=%~2"
if /i "%~1"=="-w" set "window=%~2"
if /i "%~1"=="-l" set "length=%~2"
if /i "%~1"=="-p" set "port=%~2"
if /i "%~1"=="-d" set "duration=%~2"
if /i "%~1"=="-b" set "bandwidth=%~2"
if /i "%~1"=="-f" set "output=%~2"
if /i "%~1"=="-d" set "debug=%~2"
shift
shift
if not "%~1"=="" goto :PARSE
echo "%ipaddr%"
echo "%iterations%"
echo "%sleepTime%"
echo "%window%"
echo "%length%"
echo "%port%"
echo "%duration%"
echo "%bandwidth%"
echo "%output%"
echo "%debug%"
pause
```

Answer (score 1):

Ahh, I see.  I wasn't thinking clearly through the position of each argument.  Once I have identified the flag I'm processing (e.g. '-c', I then want to assign not %1 (-c) to a variable but rather %2.  And then I want to shift off both the flag and the actual value, with a stuttered 'shift shift'

```
%0 = program name
%1 = -c 
%2 = foo
```

Working snippet of code:

```
REM Grab command-line parameters
:PARSE
if "%~1"=="" goto ENDPARSE
if "%~1"=="-c" set ipaddr=%2
if "%~1"=="-i" set iterations=%2
if "%~1"=="-s" set sleepTime=%2
if "%~1"=="-w" set window=%2
if "%~1"=="-l" set length=%2
if "%~1"=="-p" set port=%2
if "%~1"=="-t" set duration=%2
if "%~1"=="-b" set bandwidth=%2
if "%~1"=="-o" set output=%2
if "%~1"=="-d" set debug=%2
shift
shift
goto PARSE
:ENDPARSE
```

Thank you for the assistance,

--sk